# How to upgrade WASM app to NET5 framework?

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I've decided to upgrade one of my projects to the latest .NET version (.NET 5).

It consists of one asp.net core app (web api) targeting netcoreapp3.1 and a blazor WASM project targeting netstandard2.1.
after updating targetframework to net5.0 in both projects, api project is working fine but not the WASM project.

what are the steps that I should follow for upgrading?

p.s. I have latest visual studio (Version 16.8.1) and dotnet (version 5.0.100)

The error message in Blazor app:

> HTTP Error 500.33 - ANCM Request Handler Load Failure
> Common solutions to this issue:
> Make sure Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is referenced by your application.
> Specific error detected by ANCM:
> Could not find the assembly 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll' referenced for the in-process application. Please confirm the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is referenced in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade you need to make some code change as well, here is what you need to do on WASM project:

On `.csproj` file of WASM project:

1. Change `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">`
2. Change `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`
3. Remove `<RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>`
4. Remove package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build`
5. Update all other packages to latest version `5.0.0`

On `wwwroot/index.html`:

6. Change `<app>Loading...</app>` to `<div id="app">Loading...</div>`

On `Program.Main`:

7. Change `builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app")` to `builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app")`
8. Change registration of `HttpClient` to be `Scoped` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

After these changes the error should be gone.

Read about more extended scenarios [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#update-blazor-webassembly-projects)